# Ansible : The loop variable 'item' is already in use

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to run a task in ansible something similar to the following.

```
#Task in Playbook

    - name : Include tasks 
      block:
      - name: call example.yml
        include_tasks: "example.yml"
        vars:
          my_var: item
        with_items:
        - [1, 2]
```

```
# example.yml

- name: Debug.
  debug:
    msg:
    - "my_var: {{ my_var }}"
  with_inventory_hostnames:
    - 'all'
```

I expect the output to be printing the `my_var` as values 1 in the first iteration and 2 in second iteration of the loop in the playbook. But instead, it is printing the hostnames

```
# Output

TASK [proxysql : Debug.] ************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: The loop variable 'item' is already in use. You should set the `loop_var` value in the `loop_control` option for the task to something else to avoid variable collisions and unexpected behavior.
ok: [10.1xx.xx.xx] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        "my_var: 10.134.34.34"
    ]
}
ok: [10.1xx.xx.xx] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        "my_var: 10.123.23.23"
    ]
}
ok: [10.1xx.xx.xx] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        "my_var: 10.112.12.12"
    ]
}

TASK [proxysql : Debug.] ************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: The loop variable 'item' is already in use. You should set the `loop_var` value in the `loop_control` option for the task to something else to avoid variable collisions and unexpected behavior.
ok: [10.1xx.xx.xx] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        "my_var: 10.134.34.34"
    ]
}
ok: [10.1xx.xx.xx] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        "my_var: 10.123.23.23"
    ]
}
ok: [10.1xx.xx.xx] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        "my_var: 10.112.12.12"
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. In the playbook, tasks are included in a loop that has the loop variable name `item` and the included task also has a loop and
   the default variable name is again `item`. This is why the warning
   messages and to solve that use `loop_control`.
2. `my_var: item` assignment needs to be in format `my_var: "{{ item }}"` for correct assignment.

After both the corrections, playbook would look like this.

```yaml
  - name : Include tasks 
    block:
    - name: call example.yml
      include_tasks: "example.yml"
      vars:
        my_var: "{{ outer_item }}" 
      with_items:
      - [1, 2]
      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer_item
```